# Django--Should I use Through Table to Structure M2M relationship

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I want to represent clubs which have multiple members (each member can also join multiple clubs).

I created the following model

```
   class Club(models.Model):
        name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
        admin=models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='club_admins')
        member=models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='memberships')
        posts=models.ManyToManyField(Post, blank=True, null=True)   
        description=models.TextField(max_length=500,blank=True)
        public=models.BooleanField(default=True)
        password=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
          return self.name
```

My issue right now is that I'm associating clubs with Posts and I'm not sure how to then disassociate them without deleting all of the associations.

That may not be entirely clear.  I have a view that contains the following snippet:

```
       if request.POST.get('clubs'):
                clubs=request.POST['clubs'].split(',')
                p=int(post.id)
                old_clubs=Club.objects.filter(posts__pk=p)
                for o in old_clubs:
                    #figure out how to disassociate the club with this post

                for a in clubs:
                    group=Club.objects.get(name=a)
                    group.posts.add(post)
```

What I'm attempting to do is clear out all the old clubs that have a M2M relationship with this Post and then form new relationships.  This is all based on a user editing their post.

I'm not sure how to get at that intermediary table without deleting all Clubs or all Posts or all Posts associated with a Club (as opposed to just select Posts).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i do not misunderstand, you do not need to use **through** . Any M2Mfield that **do not** use through have **add(item)**, **remove(item)**, **all()** and **clear()** methods, so

```
post = Post.objects.get(id=post.id)
post.clubs.clear()
```

You can use **all()** to list all related data, and **add(item)** and **remove(item)** to add or remove a spesific one.

For more, check [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your issue, can this be of any help?

```
post = Post.objects.get(id=post.id)
post.clubs_set.clear()
```